# Refactoring methods using Java generics

Tags: java, refactoring

I have the following two methods:

```
public void doStuffA(String str, List<ClassA> list){
    list.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getObjValue().equalsIgnoreCase(str))
            .findFirst()
            .ifPresent( obj ->{
                throw new RuntimeException();
            });
}

public void doStuffB(String str, List<ClassB> list){
    list.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getObjValue().equalsIgnoreCase(str))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .findFirst()
            .ifPresent( obj ->{
                throw new RuntimeException();
            });
}
```

Both ClassA and Class B have the same method getObjValue, but they have no relationship. they dont inherit from common class or interface.
Since the methods are almost identical, can I somehow use generics to deduplicate this code with a method that has a signature like this one:

```
public void doStuffB(String str, List<?> list)
```

Comment: No, not in a type-safe way or without using reflection, because Java does not have [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) (or structural typing), so there is no way to work with unrelated types that happen to have a particular method. Obvious solution is make an interface with the method, then make `ClassA` and `ClassB` implement the interface, and accept a `List<MyInterface>` in the method.

Comment: Or well, you could create a wrapper class that can be created from either a ClassA or a ClassB instance, and that implements the necessary interface. But of course, that means one wrapper object per original object in the lists. And then you can have doStuff(String str, List < WrapperClass >)

Comment: No, with a caveat, there has to be some commonality between the objects if you're going to use them the same way.  HOWEVER, You could use reflection to lookup of the method name and invoke it directly, but I would STRONGLY advise against such code.

Comment: There are some issues with the things above. -1- Does `getObjValue()` return `boolean`,, or did you rather intend `map(s -> s.getObjValue())` -2- That `collect(Collectors.toList()).findFirst()` -3- (findFirst) ifPresent throw` stays too long in the Stream, better `if (... .anyMatch(...)) throw`. -4- Please `throw new IllegalStateException` or `IllegalArgumentException` rather than the base `RuntimeException`

Comment: the predicate is s -> s.getObjValue().equalsIgnoreCase(str), I will edit. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to completely eliminate the duplication if classA and classB do not share a common interface or superclass that declares `String getObjValue()`.

I'm assuming that the line 3 of `doStuffB()` (the line `.collect(Collectors.toList())` that prevents your sample code from compiling) can be safely removed, so that `doStuffA()` and `doStuffB()` do really the same thing.

You can then reduce the bulk of the duplication by factoring out the stream processing and using a `Predicate` :

```
public void doStuffA(String str, List<ClassA> list) {
    doStuff(str, list, s -> s.getObjValue().equalsIgnoreCase(str));
}

public void doStuffB(String str, List<ClassB> list) {
    doStuff(str, list, s -> s.getObjValue().equalsIgnoreCase(str));
}

private <T> void doStuff(String str, List<T> list, Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
    list.stream()
        .filter(predicate)
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent( obj -> {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        });
}
```